# How to avoid overflow in realloc?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, realloc, calloc

One can safely allocate `x` elements of size `y` in C by using `calloc(x, y)` and `calloc()` will take care of the multiplication `x*y`.

However `realloc()` for example only takes the new size as parameter and I was wondering how I could safely realloc `x*y` bytes using `realloc()`.

What if `x*y` doesn't fit in `size_t`? How does `calloc()` handle this?

Comment: Just a thought: If you need to worry about overflow for allocating size, probably you need to break down the algo into smaller sub-parts?

Comment: @SouravGhosh This is part of a datatype library for other persons to use and they only need to provide element size and number of elements they want to store. How can I use `realloc` to do this safely (I already have some memory - so `calloc` is not an option)?

Comment: If you need more than 4GB of memory for your algorithm, then there are serious problems :D

Comment: @tilz0R This is used in a datatype. What is wrong with me about caring about overflow?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with you, just mention it :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh The usual reason to worry about overflow during this multiplication is security. There have been numerous exploits where a protocol/user input provides a far too large number of elements in an array and the allocation succeeds because the multiplication wraps to a small number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `size_t` is an unsigned type, and the maximum value of `size_t` is the absolute maximum size of object that can be allocated with `realloc` or `malloc`; this is available in the macro `SIZE_MAX`. On 32-bit personal computers the `size_t` is often 32 bits; 64 bits on 64-bit computers. It should be enough.

To ensure that the calculation of `item_size * n_items` does not overflow, you can divide the `SIZE_MAX` by `item_size` and ensure that the resulting value is greater than or equal to `n_items`:

```
size_t max_items = SIZE_MAX / item_size;
if (max_items < n_items) {
    // an overflow would occur
}
else {
    // it is ok
}
```

`calloc` must return `NULL` if the allocation did not succeed, so `calloc` most probably has a check similar to one above.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll upvote as soon as I can (currently not enough rep).

Comment: `calloc()` _can_ allocate _arrays_ larger than `SIZE_MAX`, it is not prevent by the spec.  Post your C spec citation to support for "the maximum value of size_t is the absolute maximum size of object that can be allocated with realloc "

Comment: @chux it's implicit, surely?

Comment: @Alnitak My error. I read you answer as "maximum value of size_t is the absolute maximum size of object that can be allocated with **calloc**.  I agree with the limitation of `malloc(), realloc()` but not with `calloc()`

Comment: @chux it's not my answer

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't do it safely.   The most you can do is limit the amount of memory you attempt to allocate so it does not exceed `SIZE_MAX`.

`SIZE_MAX` is the maximum value that can be produced by the `sizeof` operator.

Every data type in C must have a size that can be computed using `sizeof`, including arrays, and any contiguous block of memory allocated using `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()`.

If `x*y` is mathematically greater than `SIZE_MAX`, then it is not possible to allocate that amount of memory by any means.   Even if the underlying system supports that, the C program will not be able to use that memory block entirely.

There is also a concern that computing `x*y` (assuming `x` and `y` are of type `size_t`) will use modulo arithmetic, so will actually give the result mathematically equivalent to `(x*y)%(SIZE_MAX + 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

> What if x*y doesn't fit in size_t? How does `calloc()` handle this?

`realloc()` and `malloc()` are limited in that the size argument passed to them is limited to `SIZE_MAX`.  Not so with `calloc()`

A compliant C implementation is *not* required to limit `calloc()` to allocating memory of only `SIZE_MAX`.  The following *may* work.  An single type can have a maximum size of `SIZE_MAX` and an *array* size can be as large as `SIZE_MAX` <strike>SIZE_MAX-1</strike> "bytes", yet `iptr` below is not an array, but a pointer.

```
// Assume sizeof(double) == 8
double *iptr = calloc(SIZE_MAX, sizeof *iptr);
```

Re-allocating such large pointers is problematic as it requires using another call to `calloc()`

---

> How to avoid overflow in `realloc`?

OP's problem is not so much of what `realloc()` can handle but of how code calculates the values passed to it may overflow.

To insure an *unsigned* type, like `size_t`, does not overflow multiplication:

```
  if (b && a > SIZE_MAX/b) Handle_Overflow();
  prod = a*b;
```

Comment: Can't an array size be as large as `SIZE_MAX`, with indices as large as `SIZE_MAX-1`?

Comment: @DavidBowling Certainly an array size can be `SIZE_MAX-1` and I now certain you are correct that the size can even be 1 more or: `SIZE_MAX`.  Yet I was not focusing on that issue nearly so much as that `calloc()` can allocate more memroy in one call than `SIZE_MAX`.  Unfortunately  I do find many implementations do not properly detect/handle overflow in `calloc()` and so such large allocations are thus inherently ID, even if  the spec does not allow it.

Comment: The issue with `calloc()` was what I took to be the salient point; I had not noticed this difference between `calloc()` and `malloc()` before, but obvious now. Documentation about maximum size of arrays seems scattered in the Standard, but I found a reference in §6.5.3.4 of [revision 5.10 of the C99 Rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) (PDF) that seemed informative.

Comment: @DavidBowling The maximum size of array has nothing directly to do with`*alloc()`  .  Which is your concern, arrays, or allocation functionality/limitations?

Comment: Arrays. The statement "an array size can be as large as `SIZE_MAX-1`" had me looking for a reference. The best I could find in the C11 Standard was §6.7.6.2/1: "If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the expression shall have an integer type." This had me wondering if an array could have more than `SIZE_MAX` elements, since this is only guaranteed to be at least 65535. It seems that `size_t` would need to be comparable to the widest `unsigned` integer type, but I don't see this in the Standard. What am I missing?

Comment: @DavidBowling An array may have more than 65535 if `SIZE_MAX` is larger.  As the `sizeof` yields the _size_: "The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand,", and its type is `size_t` and the max value of a `size_t` is `SIZE_MAX`, all arrays are <= `SIZE_MAX` in "byte" size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139800/discussion-between-chux-and-david-bowling).

Answer (score 0):

`size_t` is an unsigned type.

For unsigned types overflow behaviour is deterministic, as mentioned in `C11`

> [....] because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is
>   reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be
>   represented by the resulting type.

So, as long as you make sure the operation which produces the value to be stored in the variable type `size_t` does not overflow in the process, passing that variable to `realloc()` has no impact. At most, `realloc()` will fail to allocate that memory.

Comment: I'm trying to stay `C99` compliant. Is this also in the `C99` standard? Do you imply I should just check `x*y < x || x*y < y` and safely fail in such a case?

Comment: This should be the case in C99 also, yes.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give you my upvote as soon as I'm able to (currently not enough rep). Now I'm wondering how `calloc` handles this case? Will it fail as well of an overflow of `size_t` or will it use some kind of magic?

Comment: @user194192 What do you mean how calloc handles? The approach should be same, it takes the value provided as `size_t` and multiply with block number. If the result is huge, probably `calloc(0` will signal failure. That's it.

Comment: @user194192 : `x*y < x || x*y < y` is *NOT* a good check for overflow. Take eg. `x = 3; y = 0x80000000;` (with a 32bit `size_t`).

Answer (score 0):

If `x * y` overflows `size_t`, realloc will try to allocate that value which was overflown:

```
bytes = (x * y) % 2^(sizeof(size_t) * 8)
```

So `realloc` will "see" `bytes` amount of bytes. It does not take care of anything.

Comment: Thank you! I'm also wondering if `calloc` is able to allocate more than `sizeof(size_t) * 8` bytes or will `calloc` fail in this overflow case as well?

Comment: It is not able to allocate more.

Comment: "f x * y overflows size_t, realloc will try to allocate that value which was overflown:" is not supported by the C spec.  This behavior may be the observed behavior on your platform, but it is not specified nor should be relied on.